# Retornar as posições do maior número numa matriz

Tags: python, matriz

Preciso de um código que retorne a posição do maior elemento da matriz, e se esse elemento se repetir, que o código retorne todas as posições que esse maior elemento aparece.

Abaixo, em meu código, consigo retornar o maior valor, mas não a sua posição:

- `maior`: é o maior valor
- `posição`: posição na linha que o maior valor se encontra
- `vez`: é um contador de quantas vezes já rodei as linhas (por exemplo: estou na linha 2)

```py
from random import randint
maior = 0
posição = 0
matriz = []
vez = 0
for i in range (4):
    linha = []
    vez = vez + 1
    for j in range (4):
        linha.append(randint(1,10))
        if linha[j] > maior:
            maior = linha[j]
            posição  = j
            linha = vez

    matriz.append(linha)

print (matriz)
print ("maior: ", maior)
print ("posição do maior número: ", posição)
print ("linha: ", linha)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o maior elemento pode se repetir, então você precisa ter uma lista com todas as posições.

Se o número for igual ao maior, você adiciona a posição nesta lista. Mas se algum outro número maior ainda for encontrado, a lista de posições anteriores deve ser descartada e uma nova deve ser iniciada:

```
from random import randint
maior = 0
matriz = []
tamanho = 4
posicoes = []
for i in range(tamanho):
    linha = []
    for j in range(tamanho):
        n = randint(1, 10)
        if n > maior: # achei um maior, começa uma nova lista de posições
            posicoes = [(i, j)]
            maior = n
        elif n == maior: # igual ao maior, adicione a posição na lista
            posicoes.append((i, j))
        linha.append(n)

    matriz.append(linha)

print (matriz)
print ("maior: ", maior)
print ("posições do maior número: ", posicoes)
```

Estou guardando as posições em tuplas, contendo os valores de `i` e `j` (já que você precisa de ambos os valores para ter a posição correta).

Também eliminei a variável `vez`, que me pareceu desnecessária.

Comment: ~Interessante esse código

Answer (score 2):

Oi, seu codigo esta quase certo. A posicao depende de i,j. Entao voce tem que guardar o valor de i,j:

```
from random import randint
matriz = [-1]*4
j = 0
maior = 0
posição = ()
for i in range (4):
    for j in range (4):        
        matriz[j] = randint(1,10)
        if matriz[j] > maior:
            maior = matriz[j]
            posição = (i,j)
        j = j + 1
    print (matriz)
    print ("posição do maior número: ", posição)
print ("maior número da matriz: ", maior)
```

Para conseguir todas as posicoes que o maior numero ocorre, voce vai tem que criar uma lista de pares, e se o numero maior mudar voce vai ter que reinicializar a lista de pares e comecar a adicionar valores nela de novo.

Answer (score 1):

Pude notar que você está tentando fazer aglutinar todas as tarefas numa coisa só.

Seria melhor dividir o seu problema em etapas menores e mais simples onde em cada uma dessas etapas você fizesse apenas o essencial para resolver um problema menor.

Focando a sua pergunta:

> Preciso de um código que retorne a posição do maior elemento da
>   matriz, e se esse elemento se repetir, que o código retorne todas as
>   posições que esse maior elemento aparece.

Eu vejo as seguintes etapas:

1. Criar uma matriz
2. Descobrir qual o maior elemento da Matriz
3. Descobrir quais as posições de ocorrência do maior elemento na Matriz.

Para criar uma matriz não tem mistério, é lista composta por listas isomórficas onde a quantidade de linhas da lista exterior é a mesma quantidade de elementos contidos em uma das listas interiores. Para simplificar é um lista onde o número de linhas é o mesmo número de colunas, traduzindo isso em [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lambda d: [[randint(1,10) for _ in range(d)] for _ in range(d)]
```

Uma lista de números aleatórios, entre 1 e 10, onde o número de linhas é o mesmo que o número de colunas.

Para encontrar o maior elemento da matriz crie uma lista com os maiores elementos de cada linha e a partir dessa lista apenas encontre o maior elemento e esse será o maior elemento da matriz:

```
lambda m: max(list(map(max, m)))
```

O mais trabalhoso é encontrar as posições de ocorrência do maior elemento e mesmo assim não é nada demais. É precorrer as linhas da matriz coletar o índices dessas ocorrências e criar uma tupla (linha,coluna) de onde foram encontrados ocorrência do maior elemento:

```
def posição(elemento, matriz):
  ocorrencias = []
  for linha in range(len(matriz)):
    o = [i for i,v in enumerate(matriz[linha]) if v==elemento]
    for i in o:      
      ocorrencias.append((linha,i))
  return ocorrencias
```

---

Juntando tudo:

```
import pprint #Usado para melhorar a impressão da matriz 
from random import randint

matriz = lambda d: [[randint(1,10) for _ in range(d)] for _ in range(d)]

maior = lambda m: max(list(map(max, m)))

def posição(elemento, matriz):
  ocorrencias = []
  for linha in range(len(matriz)):
    o = [i for i,v in enumerate(matriz[linha]) if v==elemento]
    for i in o:      
      ocorrencias.append((linha,i))
  return ocorrencias    

mat = matriz(4)
mat_max = maior(mat)
mat_max_occor = posição(mat_max, mat)    

pprint.pprint(mat,width=20) #Usado para melhorar a impressão da matriz 
print(f'\nvalor máximo:{mat_max}')
print(f'Posições de ocorrencia do valor máximo:{mat_max_occor}')
```

Código funcionando no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/UltimateCulturedPresses

Funções utilizadas:
 `max()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max
 `map()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map
 `list()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list
 `enumerate()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate